# What type of shelving is this?

Tags: wood, shelving

I would like to use the same type of wooden planking used for shelving as in this picture:

[image: Wooden shelving on standards]

Unfortunately, having searched for a while I cannot identify it. Any thoughts?

Comment: That is double slot adjustable track shelving. I have some of it. Every big box store carries some brand of it. Finding those specific shelf brackets that might be actually hard.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear at all, I meant the actual wood used for the shelves. I'll edit my question.

Comment: The shelves appear to be made out of three-ply cross-laminated pine. They appear to be 3/4 inch thick with 1/4 inch ply.